# WebView slow loading

Tags: cocoa, macos, webview

In a cocoa / Mac app I am using a WebView to load a series of YouTube videos (5). When it is loading my whole application locks up for 5 seconds or so.

Is there a way I can load it so it doesn't freeze the rest of the application?

Thanks

eg:

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtube.com"]];
```

Comment: sounds like it is loading the page on the main thread, how are you setting the page urls? post some of the code?

Comment: Hi McCannon, I added the line above, I tried running it in a background thread and it just bombed out. Is there a trick?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot render a WebView except on the main thread. This is a basic limitation of the class. I would begin investigating why your page takes so long to render. My hunch: Javascript or a plugin.

I usually like to start by using Safari to see if it has the same issues. You can drag an HTML file onto Safari to load it easily. If Safari shows the same problem, then you can use Safari's Develop tools to profile it. (Preferences, Advanced, Show Develop menu in menu bar.)

If Safari doesn't have a problem, that's actually good, because it means your problem is definitely solvable (if Safari can do it, you should be able to achieve the same thing). Here are some things to try out:

- Instruments. Try to see what WebView is taking its time on. Focus first on "all samples" for the main thread. This is usually what leads to the app hanging.
- Simplification. Try stripping things out of the webview, especially javascript, until you find the piece that's causing the problem.
- Implement the `WebResourceLoadDelegate` methods to see what piece seems to be causing the problem. The information given by this can be misleading, since it has to do with when things are downloaded, not when they are rendered, but it can give a sense of where in the page you're hanging.